# Convert [object Object] to JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to pass some params from js to rails. And because the params are too long, I have to use `post` method and make the params be JSON, not string. But I can't change the parts back to JSON in rails.

```
<ActionController::Parameters {" "=>nil, "test"=>"[object Object]", "controller"=>"super", "action"=>"addArticle"} permitted: false>
```

And I want to get the params in `parms[:test]` [sic]. But I can only get this:

```
params[:test]
#=> [object Object]
```

So, please help me.

Comment: This `[object Object]` indicates that you didn't pass the params properly from JavaScript, so this question should not be about Ruby at all.

Comment: The problem is that you are sending "[object Object]" as an string itself, it's not a real Object, the problem is in JS, not Rails

Comment: @MarekLipka Thank you for your comment.And I will change my question.

Comment: @JosepJoestar Thank you for your comment.And I will change my question.

Comment: you need to call `JSON.stringify` before adding to the url params

Comment: @maxpleaner I have tried to do this.But my params have be encoded with encodeURIComponent and if I use JSON.stringify,it will be too long with url.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are passing the object like so in your call

```
$.ajax.post('/to/some/url', data: { test: js_object } );
```

where `test` is something like `{ "some" : "value" }`.

What you need to do is to first stringify the object. Something like this should do:

```
$.ajax.post('/to/some/url', data: { test: JSON.stringify(js_object) } );
```

When you send objects directly, they are converted to a string by JavaScript and when JS converts an object to string automatically, it converts it into `[object Object]`.

To prove, just run the these lines in console one after another:

```
console.log({a:'b'});
console.log({a:'b'}.toString());
console.log(JSON.stringify({a:'b'}));
```

You will figure out the difference!

Comment: Thank you.I have tried to do this.But my params have be encoded with encodeURIComponent and if I use JSON.stringify,it will be too long with url. And I have found some answers about this question that I can use POST method and  pass data in JSON.

Comment: I think you should use POST for any data that can potentially become too big for a URL in any encoding.